# How homogenous lists are useful in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, mit-scheme

I have started learning Haskell a few months ago. Also know programming in another functional language Scheme which uses heterogeneous lists. I would like to know the advantages and disadvantages of both type of lists so that can compare both designs.

Comment: How is your question different from asking how static typing (vs. dynamic typing) is useful?

Comment: Well they seem to be the same questions. However, for now I am just concerned with data type of the elements of a list.

Comment: Homogeneous lists are not really a "design".  They're just a thing that happens to be.  Since homogeneous lists are obviously useful, I think you probably mean "how can Haskell do *without* heterogeneous lists".

Comment: @AndrewC Only works for "lists" of compile-time fixed length.

Comment: @delnan You're correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Advantages of Homogeneous lists

It all has to do with the types my friend. Like take as an example, type signatures:

```
concat :: [ByteString] -> ByteString
```

It is clear from this type signature that it takes a list of strings, and put them together. This wouldn't be possible with heterogeneous lists, because it wouldn't be easy to express a lists type. Another thing to consider is that your functions that have to worry about different types of objects. Another thing to consider is a compromise between heterogeneous and homogeneous lists: existential types.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Showable = forall a. Show a => Pack a
instance Show Showable where
    show (Pack a)=show a

showableList :: [Showable]
showableList = [Pack 1, Pack "Yolo", Pack 5.2, Pack (3, 4), Pack ["A", "B", "C"], Pack 'c']

main=print showableList
```

This allows the parts of the list to be different types, but they can only be used in the same way. This could work with, say, shapes. If they where all part of a shapes class, you could do thigs like get their area and such, but no their radius.

Comment: Existentials aren't usually advisable though, especially to beginners (they tend to encourage an "OO-style" that doesn't work out nearly as nicely as the more idiomatic (if less-aquainted) parametric polymorphism).