# How to traverse a list/tuple that contains various/different types in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

There are scenarios that types of values contained in list/tuple as a general term are different.

For instance, [length](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=length) has polymorphism,

```
Prelude> length [7,5,3]
3
Prelude> length ["foo","bar"]
2
```

and now, we have lists of different types,

```
numbers :: [Int]
numbers = [7, 5, 3]

strings :: [[Char]]
strings = ["foo", "bar"]
```

then, **we want to create a function that takes a list of lists and returns the number of elements of the list for each.** *(Please don't ask me why and limiting the purpose or possibility of programming in general sense.)*

When the list is Monoid, it's easy,

```
data0 :: [[Int]]
data0 = [numbers, numbers]

counter :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
counter = \listOfList ->
  map (\list -> length list) listOfList

count :: [Int]
count = counter data0 -- [3, 3]
```

So, in Haskell, in order to deal list containing non-identical type, we need to use tuple although I know there is an exception. `{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}` [How homogenous lists are useful in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891868/how-homogenous-lists-are-useful-in-haskell)

```
data1 :: ([Int], [[Char]])
data1 = (numbers, strings)
```

It might be

```
maybes :: [Maybe a]
maybes = [Just 9, Nothing]

data2 :: ([Int], [[Char]], [Maybe a])
data2 = (numbers, strings, maybes)
```

The data of list is not fixed.

It seems there is no build-in function to map/traverse for tuples [Manipulating Tuples in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64336131/manipulating-tuples-in-haskell) .

How do we achieve this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242561/discussion-on-question-by-functor-how-to-traverse-a-list-tuple-that-contains-var).